# To receive value of tinymce dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, tinymce

I am trying to retrieve the value of multiple textarea with the tinymce that gives me the rich format, but eh not able to get me to send all the values, someone who can help me? I leave my code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover
table-heading no-border-bottom" id="field_grid6">
 <thead><tr>
    <th>STEP</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
    <th>RESULTS/DESCRIPTIONS</th>
    <th>TIME</th>
</tr></thead>
 <tbody><tr> 
    <td> <input type="text" value=""  name="91a[]" placeholder="step" class="form-controlS1" /><br>
  <select class="form-controlS2" name="admotiona[]">
 <option value="">Admotion</option>
 <option value="danger">DANGER</option>
 <option value="warning">WARNING</option>
 <option value="caution">CAUTION</option>
  </select><br>
  <select class="form-controlS3" name="admotion1[]">
 <option value="">Disruption</option>
 <option value="Service">SERVICE</option>
 <option value="Network">NETWORK</option>
  </select><br>
   <textarea rows="4" name="c4Rachel" cols="50" class="form-controlS4"></textarea></td>
    <td> <textarea name="92a[]" cols="70" rows="70" class="form-controlS5"></textarea></td>
    <td> <textarea name="93a[]" cols="70" rows="70"  class="form-controlS6"></textarea></td>
    <td> <input type="text"  value="" name="94a[]" placeholder="time" class="form-controlS7" /></td>
</tr></tbody>
  </table>
  <button id="add_field6" class="btn btn-default">Add Field <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  <script type="text/template6" id="template6">
 <tr><td>
   <input type="text" class="form-controlS1" value=""  name="91a[]" placeholder="step" /><br>
  <select class="form-controlS2" name="admotiona[]">
 <option value="">Admotion</option>
 <option value="danger">DANGER</option>
 <option value="warning">WARNING</option>
 <option value="caution">CAUTION</option>
  </select><br>
  <select class="form-controlS3" name="admotion1[]">
 <option value="">Disruption</option>
 <option value="Service">SERVICE</option>
 <option value="Network">NETWORK</option>
  </select><br>
    <textarea rows="4" name="c4Rachel" cols="50" class="form-controlS4"></textarea></td>
<td><textarea  name="92a[]" cols="70" class="form-controlS5" ></textarea<br>
</td><td><textarea name="93a[]" cols="70" class="form-controlS6" ></textarea>
</td><td>
    <input type="text" class="form-controlS7" value=""  name="94a[]" placeholder="time" /></td>
<td><a href="#" class="btn-remove6"><li class="fa fa-trash-o"> </li></a</td>
 </tr></script>
```

//// in this part enters the function to generate more rows dynamically

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addField6() {
      $($('#template6').html()).appendTo('#field_grid6 tbody');

        tinymce.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        selector: "textarea",
        editor_selector : "c4Rachel",
        toolbar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                   tinymce.triggerSave();
            });
        }
    });
        }

        function removeField(e) {
            if($('input[type=text]').parents('tbody').find('tr').length <= 2) {
                return false;
            }
            var row = $(e).closest('tr').remove();
        }

        $(function() {
            $('#field_grid6').on('click', '.btn-remove6', function(e) {
                removeField(e.target);
                return e.preventDefault();
            });

            $('#add_field6').click(function(e) {
                addField6();
                return e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
</script>
```

and finally I get the values in this part

```
function saveSteps(){
    alert("Save Steps function test");
    var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
    var signum = document.getElementById("signum1").value;
    var idmop = document.getElementById("idmop").value;
    var inputs1 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS1' ), s1 = [].map.call(inputs1, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
    var inputs2 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS2' ), s2 = [].map.call(inputs2, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
    var inputs3 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS3' ), s3 = [].map.call(inputs3, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
    var inputs4 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS4' ), s4 = [].map.call(inputs4, function( input ) {
        return input.value=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() ;
    }).join( '+ ' );


    var inputs5 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS5' ), s5  = [].map.call(inputs5, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
    var inputs6 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS6' ), s6 = [].map.call(inputs6, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
    var inputs7 = document.getElementsByClassName( 'form-controlS7' ), s7 = [].map.call(inputs7, function( input ) { 
        return input.value;
    }).join( '+ ' );
}     alert(s4);

//saveStepsbd(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7) }
```

the problem is that it only sends the values of the textarea active and I need you to bring me all, please help

Comment: Why do you have part of a table in `script` tags?

Comment: It remains invisible until I need it in $($('#template6').html()).appendTo('#field_grid6 tbody');

Comment: You should comment it out. That _can_ cause syntax errors. Open your browser console to see syntax errors. This will help you so much when working with javascript. Also to start a html comment use `<!--` and to end the comment use `-->` *Example* `<!-- <p>something</p><br><div>else</div>-->`

Comment: Done thanks, but that didn't solve the issue...

Comment: Correct, that wouldn't solve your problem. This is why I'm posting in the comments, I hope that helps you. I will come back to this when I finish work. If you don't have a solution by then I will see if I can help you. I wish you luck.